# Fill amCharts line path and remove yAxes values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using amCharts to create this:

[image]

I'm having the following issues:

1. I can't get the y axis labels to disappear. After looking at the [documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/auto-hide-value-axes/), I've tried `theYAxis.disabled = true;`
2. I want the everything below the line graph to fill with blue. At the moment, mine just shows a line. I've tried:

```js
var range = xAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.theXAxis.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(8);
range.theXAxis.fillOpacity = 0.2;
```

Where am I going wrong?

**Demo**:

```js
var chart = am4core.create("dataChart", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
    "xValue": "Q1",
    "yValue": 3
}, {
    "xValue": "Q2",
    "yValue": 4
}, {
    "xValue": "Q3",
    "yValue": 7
}, {
    "xValue": "Q4",
    "yValue": 2
}, {
    "xValue": "Q5",
    "yValue": 9
}];

/* Create axes */
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";

// tryin to get line to fill below
//var range = xAxis.axisRanges.create();
//range.theXAxis.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(8);
//range.theXAxis.fillOpacity = 0.2;

/* Create value axis */
var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
//theYAxis.disabled = true; // . trying to disable . to 1-10 showing here


/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY} / 10";

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
#dataChart{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="dataChart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the labels, you have to disable the labels direclty on the axis renderer, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Grid_labels_and_ticks)

```
theYAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
```

If you just need a basic fill underneath the line, set the `fill` and `fillOpacity` directly on the series.

```
series.stroke = "#000088"; //for the line
series.fill = "#000088";  // for the fill
series.fillOpacity = .3;
```

```js
var chart = am4core.create("dataChart", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
    "xValue": "Q1",
    "yValue": 3
}, {
    "xValue": "Q2",
    "yValue": 4
}, {
    "xValue": "Q3",
    "yValue": 7
}, {
    "xValue": "Q4",
    "yValue": 2
}, {
    "xValue": "Q5",
    "yValue": 9
}];

/* Create axes */
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";

// tryin to get line to fill below
//var range = xAxis.axisRanges.create();
//range.theXAxis.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(8);
//range.theXAxis.fillOpacity = 0.2;

/* Create value axis */
var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
//theYAxis.disabled = true; // . trying to disable . to 1-10 showing here
theYAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY} / 10";
series1.fill = "#000088";
series1.fillOpacity = .3;
series1.stroke = "#000088";

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
#dataChart{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="dataChart"></div>
```